# Highcharts with JSON

Tags: php, ajax, json, highcharts

I'm trying to create a chart using data from my database calling json, but its not showing the results in the chart. 
Here's my code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function requestData() {
$.ajax({
        url: 'data.php',
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
        chart.series[0].setData(data[0]);
        },
        cache: false
    });
}
var chart;
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'line',
            events: {
               load: requestData
            }
            },
    xAxis: {
  },
  yAxis: {
     title: {
        text: 'Value'
     }
  },

series: [{
         name: 'Random data',
         data: []
            }]
});

});
```

And here's my data.php code

```
$query = "SELECT tiempo,Fp1Ref 
        FROM GraficaEEG limit 10";
$data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
$i=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
    $row['tiempo'] = (float) $row['tiempo'];
    $rows[$i]=array($row['tiempo'],(float)$row['Fp1Ref']); 
    $i++;
}
echo json_encode($rows);
```

The data i receive is this:

```
[[0,3001],[0.005,4937.22],[0.01,4130.55],[0.015,4213.15],[0.02,4010.61],[0.025,3914.34],[0.03,3785.33],[0.035,3666.13],[0.04,3555.25],[0.045,3447.77]]
```

So i think is the proper way to pass data for the chart, so i don't quite get whats wrong, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that when your *requestData()* function is fired the *chart* variable still isn't fully built and doesn't know it has the *series* property.
To fix this, instead of *chart* in your *requestData()* function, reference *this* (which means the chart object in that context).
I tried this out in jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/elcabo/p2r6g/.
Also post the js code below.

```
$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function() {

        //Function bits
        function requestData(event) {
            var tiemposAlAzar = [[10,20],[20,50]];
            //The 'this' will refer to the chart when fired
            this.series[0].setData(tiemposAlAzar);
        };

        var chart;

        //Chart bits
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'line',
                events:{
                    load: requestData                           
                }
            },
            xAxis: {},
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                text: 'Value'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Random data',
            data: []
        }]
      });
    });
});​
```

Comment: I tried this and it gives me this error now: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`  in the ajax call. Thanks for the answer btw.

Comment: I don't know what was my error, but i used the $.getJSON call and it works, thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 0):

This url may help you to create dynamic highchart that need to pull data from database.

In json.php code you can put your sql query and replace static array to dynamic array

```
http://www.kliptu.com/free-script/dynamic-highchart-example-with-jquery-php-json
```

The example also shows how to manage multiple series with json. 
And tooltips with all series data at mouse point.

You can modify example as per your script requirement.